# Construct a variable with command parameters that contains a space

Tags: bash

I have the following in a bash script

```
COUNTRY="$(findcountry /data/list.tab)"
PARAMS="--name=Test"
PARAMS="$PARAMS --country=$COUNTRY"
./program $PARAMS
```

If `$(findcountry /data/list.tab)` returns e.g. Mexico, there is no issue.
But if it returns United States, there's an issue because of the space.

In that case calls the "program" with 3 arguments, because one of the arguments contains a space. like it was called like so:

```
./program '--name=Test' '--country=United' 'States'
```

The program does not understand this, it expects there to be only 2 arguments, like.

```
./program '--name=Test' '--country=United States'
```

How can I fix this ?

(Note that the 4 lines of bash script is just a vast simplification, there are a lot more arguments than the 2 shown here that I add to my $PARAMS , all which could also have the issue of containing whitespace..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array; it's what they're made for.

```
COUNTRY="$(findcountry /data/list.tab)"
PARAMS=( "--name=Test" )
PARAMS+=("--country=$COUNTRY")
./program "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

When a string is used unquoted, it is split on the values of IFS.
That is something you want to use to separate both arguments.

A very simple solution that works for two arguments is:

```
country="$(findcountry /data/list.tab)"
params="--name=Test"
./program "$params" "--country=$country"
```

For more arguments, you should use an array variable and `+=`:

```
country="$(findcountry /data/list.tab)"
params+=("--country=$country")
params+=("--name=Test")

./program "${params[@]}"
```